# Visual Code not showing unused imports/variables anymore

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I used to have unused imports/variables shown in a lighter color then normal so you could spot them. I just noticed however that I have unused imports that are not showing anymore.

I disabled Beautify and Typescript hero etc. and switched back to the default skin but still nothing.

- Version: 1.27.2
- Electron: 2.0.7
- Chrome: 61.0.3163.100
- Node.js: 8.9.3
- V8: 6.1.534.41
- Architecture: x64

Comment: You should probably provide more info, such as the version of VS Code. Also, did you recently update VS Code or any extensions?

Comment: Only the Visual Code update, but I didn't see anything in the changelog.

Comment: Does the problem still occur if you open a new folder with a trivial TypeScript file, or does it occur only on your original project?  Do other features of the TypeScript language service still work, such as underlining of errors and type information when you hover over a variable?

Comment: Occurs on every project

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies to VSCode, but in Visual Studio this worked for me:

`Tools -> Options -> Javascript/TypeScript -> Linting -> Enable ESLint`

[image]